# User Defined Table Type not working with Linq

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have created some User Defined Table Types in database(SQL Server2008) and using that kind of types as parameter in some stored procedures, when i dragged that stored procedures in dbml file(visual studio 2010) via server explorer by which database has been connected and i have dragged all tables,it gives error 'UdtTypeName Property must be set for UDT parameters' might be because there is no type in server explorer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, LINQ doesn't support User Defined Table Types.  However, someone has written a workaround:  http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2010/01/sql-2008-tvp-table-valued-parameters.html

Disclaimer:  I have not used this method, so I can't personally vouch for it.

Comment: I would like to vouch for this. :)
it worked as I hoped it would. 
the only thing is that, I had to declare the table data type at the beginning of the stored procedure.

but then again, I think I can manage with that.